# Капча с маской на PHP и JS

Tags: flash, php, javascript

Недавно наткнулся на одну интересную капчу, ее отличие в том, что ее сначала нужно "затереть", а потом читать и вводить. [Пример](http://l2top.ru/vote/3577/).

Меня интересует способ реализации и может быть есть какие-то примеры. Интересует сама "маска".

Comment: В HTML5 есть такая вещь, как canvas, думаю через неё всё сделано(затирка). А может быть это флэш?

Comment: может и флеш... не уверен точно

Comment: Теперь тоже её заинтересовался, вещь то полезная, да и с новым уровнем сложности)

Comment: Мне кажется, что капча скоро должна умереть! Скажите кого не достает ввод капчи?! Можно и так запрограммировать поведение сервера, чтобы не постили роботами. Что касается гибкости второго метода, то да кпча выигрывает, но на отношение к формам заполнения на конечных пользователях проигрывает. Так может пусть будет второй метод защиты?

Comment: Помнится, долго игрался с капчей, состоящей из набора мини-квестов (со случайным выбором) - пазл собрать, картинки попереворачивать, барабан покрутить) Жаль, ссылка потерялась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересная каптча)

Посмотрел, получается примерно такая схема:

1. "Маска" реализована при помощи flash
2. Flash-ка запрашивает картинку каптчи по адресу http://l2top.ru/cryptImg.php?key=[ключ] (картинку можно скачать только один раз)

Все довольно просто

Comment: Жаль, не знаю как это реализовать с flash

Comment: Там явно какие-то брачные игры с BitmapData происходят. Мне, если честно, просто лень, но вообще гуглить на тему "рисовалка как в контакте" и "как удалить часть изображения"